# HTML5 : compare video.buffered.end(0) with video.duration

Tags: html, html5-video, setinterval

I'm trying to compare whether the video has been fully downloaded before I fade in the player using jQuery. To do this I'm using a loop using the setInterval() function and comparing the video attributes 'buffered.end(0)' and 'duration', however the length of both differs - as the first one contains more decimal places (by 3) than the second one:

```
25.946847656 > 25.946847
```

Is there any way I could check whether the video has been fully downloaded before I show the player?

Here's what I've got at the moment:

```
var playerObject = {
    init : function(obj) {
        "use strict";
        if (obj.length > 0) {
            if (obj.length > 1) {
                jQuery.each(obj, function() {
                    playerObject.start($(this));    
                });
            } else {
                playerObject.start(obj);
            }
        }       
    },
    start : function(obj) {
        "use strict";
        var thisTime = window.setInterval(function() {
            if (obj[0].buffered.end(0) === obj[0].duration) {
                window.clearInterval(thisTime);
                obj.fadeIn(200);   
                playerObject.create(obj);               
            }
        }, 1000);
    },
    create : function(obj) {
        "use strict";   
        obj.live('click', function() {
            var thisVideo = $(this)[0];
            if (thisVideo.paused === false) {
                thisVideo.pause();
            } else {
                thisVideo.play();               
            }           
        }); 
        playerObject.endVideo(obj); 
    },
    endVideo : function(obj) {
        "use strict";
        var thisTime = window.setInterval(function() {
            if (obj[0].ended == true) {
                  window.clearInterval(thisTime);
                  obj.fadeOut(200);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
};
$(function() {
    "use strict";
    playerObject.init($('.player'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There dosn't appear to be anything in the HTML 5 specification which would trigger once download/buffering has completed there is however [a `canplaythrough` event](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/media-elements.html#mediaevents) that fires once the browser determines **enough** of the media has been downloaded such that it can be played through to the end without having to stop and buffer more of the media.

Comment: Thanks Simon - worth knowing.

Answer (score 0):

I've now amended the **start()** method by simply dividing both, rounding the result and comparing to 1, which would indicate that they are both the same:

```
start : function(obj) {
    "use strict";
    var thisTime = window.setInterval(function() {
          if (Math.round(obj[0].buffered.end(0) / obj[0].duration) === 1) {
                window.clearInterval(thisTime);
                obj.fadeIn(200);   
                playerObject.create(obj);               
          }
     }, 1000);
}
```